# algorithm- Rod cutting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, greedy

We are given n rods of say m meters and we wish to do the following operations:

- Cut n1 rods of length m1
- Cut n2 rods of length m2
- ....

What would be the greedy approach to solve this?

I have tried the standard backtracking problem, but this is slow. Could there be a greedy approach to solve this problem?

Also I have noticed that the highest common factor of products of n1xm1, n2xm2... should be n, although I am not sure about this, but seems to me pretty correct.

Example:

```
n=20
m=40

n1=20 m1=12
n2=40 m2=10
n3=10 m3=6
n4=25 m4=4
```

HCF of(240,400,60,100) is 20. This signifies that the problem could be solved, but I don't get the clue for my greedy approach.

Comment: What is the exact input and what is the exact output of the problem you are describing? Are we given `n1, n2...` or `m1, m2..` or are we supposed to figure that out? Is `sum(n_i * m_i)` supposed to match `n * m` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One greedy approach is to cut one rod in each iteration, starting with the maximum quantity of the longest rod that you can support, filling in with shorter ones at the end.  Then recur with the remaining requirements for the remaining rods.  The first step in this case would be

```
Rod 1: 3 * 12m + 1 * 4m
recur with [19, 40], [(17, 12), (40, 10), (10, 6), (24, 4)]
```

You will have identical cuts for rods 2-6, running out of 12m needs on rod 7:

```
Rod 7: 2 * 12m + 1 * 10m + 1 * 6m
```

Now, you might want a different definition of "greedy".  The two I propose are equivalent so far:

1. Start with the longest cut-rod (use the most length)
2. Start with the longest cut-rod that doesn't evenly divide the stock-rod's length (use the least obvious fit).

For rod 8, you'll start with either 10m cuts (greedy-1) or 6m cuts (greedy-2).

Also note that you could recur on each individual rod, just doing a single cut and then recurring with the remaining length.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes. Even I figured this solution on paper but wasn't sure if it would work for all. Thanks. Upvoted!

Comment: Well I found a situation where this might not work. Consider (ni, mi) as (20,17) (10,16) (20,12) (6,10). Even my hcf thing doesn't seem to ve valid here.

Comment: Right.  You asked for a greedy approach; what I posted is a *good* approach, but still requires backtracking capability to guarantee a solution.  You said that you already have backtracking.